# dynamic programming shortest path example

Tags: dynamic-programming

[image]

Could someone please show how he uses dynamic programming to solve for minimum cost of getting from 1 to 6? Is it recommended to use dynamic programming to solve this?

Edit: I know that dynamic programming on shortest path examples requires us to go from 'back to front'. So I start with:

1) 5 is closest and shortest to 6.

2)4 is closest and shortest to 5

and so on. I'm actually not sure how to use dynamic programming on this. Maybe somebody could hint me?

Comment: Could i get an explanation for why this question is being downvoted?

Comment: If you explain what you tried, and why it didn't work, me may be able to help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are algorithms specifically designed for shortest path problems, so dynamic programming is not the most common choice for it. On the other hand, small shortest path examples are commonly used to demonstrate DP (in part because they are easy to grasp).

As for how to use DP here:

- If you are at 5, the least costly (not to mention only) path to 6 costs 7.
- If you are at 4, you can go directly to 6 (cost 12) or go to 5 (cost 7) and then take the cheapest (and, as it turns out, only) route to 6 (costing another 7, for a total of 14). So the cheapest route from 4 to 6 costs 12.
- If you are at 3, [left to the reader as an exercise].
- ...